# Excel File Corrupted after downloaded

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I was using laravel to download an excel file which stored inside the public folder. The same file is uploaded and there is no issues with the file after upload. But when the file is downloaded, it couldnot be opened. It seems that the file is corrupted.

The server side function

```
public function downloadexcelfile(Request $request)
  {
    ob_end_clean();
    ob_start();
    $id = $request->id;
    $path = DB::table('tbl_excel_import_data')
      ->where('id', $id)->value('path');
    $path_2 = storage_path("app/public/{$path}");
    if (file_exists($path_2)) {
      return response()->download($path_2, 'downloaded_excel_file.xlsx', [
        'Content-Type' => 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet',
        'Content-Disposition' => 'attachment;filename=filename.xlsx',
      ]);
    } else {
      return response()->json(['error' => 'File not found'], 404);
    }
  }
```

The ajax call

```
            $.ajax({
                url: "{{ url('/scholarship/downloadexcelfile') }}",
                data: {
                    'id': id
                },
                success: (data) => {
                    
                    var blob = new Blob([data], {
                        type: 'application/octet-stream'
                    });

                    
                    var link = document.createElement('a');
                    link.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
                    link.download = 'downloaded_file.xlsx'; 
                    document.body.appendChild(link);
                    link.click();
                    document.body.removeChild(link);
                },
                error: function(data) {
                    console.log(data);
                }
            });
```

I tried several ways, but nothing seems to be working.

Comment: Open the file in an editor (either text or hex) to check the contents.